# 3rd party iOS app with twitter sign in button

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working on the authentication part of my app. I have both facebook and g+ sign in working. Both fb and g+ provides sdk that makes it easy.

I am wondering if twitter has the same thing? The ideal flow I am looking for is user taps a twitter signin button, she will leave my app and go to safari. the web page is provided by twitter and ask if she wants to give certain permissions to my app. User taps yes and automatically switches from safari back to my app (I should get a callback at this time).

I also don't want the native iOS dialogue box like "xxx wants access to your twitter account" (the same kind of dialogue box that also asks for location/camera roll permission)

Thanks!

Erben

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience myself with Twitter authentication but I have found some information for you.

Twitter seems to be referring to this as "Sign in with Twitter". A lot of information regarding OAuth, tokens and other necessary things are available here [Implementing sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter)

Hope this was helpful, feel free to ask if you have some questions. I might be able to help. :)

Cheers!